# latlng cannot be null - a position is required in Autocomplete

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-autocomplete

i am using Autocomplete search places that  get the address but not working on some addresses giving error of

> Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=131190, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: latlng cannot be null - a position is required.

here is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 116) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);

            if(priviuos.contains("new")){
                loc_txt.setText(place.getName());
                pickmarkets =  getLocationFromAddress(getContext(),place.getName());
                latlngdata ="1";
                priviuos = "old";
            }
            else{
                loc_txt.setText(place.getName());
                pickmarkets =  getLocationFromAddress(getContext(),place.getName());
                latlngdata ="1";
                priviuos = "old";
                bothgetmarkers(markets,pickmarkets);
            }


        } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);

            Log.i("mmm", status.getStatusMessage());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // The user canceled the operation.
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Probably need to include the code which issues the request.

Comment: Can you please provide your full maps-related code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete fragment is initialixed and the data that you would want to extract from the selected place is specified here.

`autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG));`

if you want to use the placeID specify

`Place.Field.ID`

and so on.
You are trying to use the place LAT_LNG but havent specified it as

`Place.Field.LAT_LNG`

as above